# Windows batch to move files into individual folders based on names

Tags: batch-file

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I have 2 set of images named as:

```
Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel001.TIFF
Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel001.TIFF

Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal001.TIFF
Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal002.TIFF
```

I need a batch script that can sort them according to their names into folders `001` and `002`.

- **001**

  - `Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel001.TIFF`
  - `Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal001.TIFF`
- **002**

  - `Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel002.TIFF`
  - `Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal002.TIFF`

And then I need another batch script to rename the files inside each sub folders:

- **001**

  - `Parallel.TIFF` *from* `Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel001.TIFF`
  - `Perp.TIFF` *from* `Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal001.TIFF`
- **002**

  - `Parallel.TIFF` *from* `Pro_NGF_Con_Parallel002.TIFF`
  - `Perp.TIFF` *from* `Pro_NGF_Con_Orthogonal002.TIFF`

Comment: what system are you running on? winXP? vista? win7?

Comment: 0h Sorry, I forgot about that. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What range of numbers are there?  is it always 3 digits?  Do you want two batch files, or just one to do the two tasks?

Comment: For the current data set, it is only 3 digits. I don't mind 2 batch files. The file number is always 001,002 but the prefix of each file may differ in each data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

batch 1:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%a in (1000,1,1999) do (
set "num=%%a"
set "num=!num:~-3!"
   if exist "*!num!.tiff" (
      md "!num!" 2>nul
      move "*!num!.tiff" "!num!"
   )
)
```

batch 2:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%a in (1000,1,1999) do (
set "num=%%a"
set "num=!num:~-3!"
   if exist "!num!\*_Parallel!num!.tiff" ren "!num!\*_Parallel!num!.tiff" "Parallel.tiff"
   if exist "!num!\*_Orthogonal!num!.tiff" ren "!num!\*_Orthogonal!num!.tiff" "Perp.tiff"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the input. I just tried running the 1st batch script. It creates the folders 001,002 etc but did not move the files into the folder. The error reads "a duplicate file name exists or the file is not found."

Comment: I edited the filemasks after posting - make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Testing the 2nd script, it did not seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version, it did not move the files.

Comment: I had a `do` where it shouldn't have been.  Try the code now.  The second one renames the files - nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: I tried the new code (batch1), it does nothing now. For the 2nd code, I manually moved some files into folders and run the script, the files were not renamed.

Comment: Just to clarify I am copying the code and pasting it into a notepad, save the file and rename it to .bat extension and execute the file in the folders, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: I just realized some of the files have extensions of .tif and not .tiff, change that in the batch 1 & 2 script, it is both working now!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I have a question. If I need 4 digits for the range of numbers, which part of the script do I need to alter to achieve that? Some where in the 3rd line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(10000,1,19999)` and change the 5th line `set "num=!num:~-4!"`